# Counter in a function showing the n iteration value

Tags: python

I have a below function which takes value from a dataframe column and process the Serial Number .
The dataframe column can have rows of any range.

```
def fetch_by_ser_no(ser_no: str) -> dict:
     ##Do soemthing###
_FETCHED = 0
 for _FETCHED in range (max) :
  _FETCHED += 1
  if _FETCHED % 50 == 0  :
    print("Checked %d certs" % (_FETCHED))
return  ret

def creat_excel(filename):
  try:
    data = pd.read_excel(filename, usecols=[4,18,19,20,26,27,28])
except Exception as e:
    sys.exit("Error reading %s: %s" % (filename, e))
 Print("1 Call")
 data["Output0"] = data['Serial Number'].apply(lambda x: fetch_by_ser_no(x))
 Print("2 call")
 data["Output1"] = data['Serial Number'].apply(lambda x: fetch_by_ser_no(x))
 Print("3 Call")
 data["Output2"] = data['Serial Number'].apply(lambda x: fetch_by_ser_no(x))
```

I want to print a statement after every 50 records processed. Also the counter should reset when the "fetch by ser no" function is called again in "creat_excel".

Desired outPut -: Suppose excel file have 200 rows.

```
   1 Call
   Checked 50 certs
   Checked 100 certs
   Checked 150 certs
   checked 200 certs
   2 Call
   Checked 50 certs
   Checked 100 certs
   Checked 150 certs
   3 Call
   Checked 50 certs
   Checked 100 certs
```

Comment: what's your current output?

Comment: I get an error now in the for _FETCHED in range(max) as invalid syntax because of max. If I remove the for statement then i cannot print "Checked 50 Certs" it only shows the "1 call"

Comment: Shouldn't your `# do something` logic be inside the `for` loop which checks the rows? Also, `max` is the name of a python inbuilt function, you can't use it as a variable name.